# Hide specific x axis **labels** in Chartjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, data-visualization, react-chartjs

I would like to hide specific x axis **labels** that are less than `moment().valueOf()`. So If I have 12:40, 12:45, 12:50 and `12:55 is the current time` then I want to display 12:55 and hide the past time interval labels. Key here is to only hide the labels not get rid of the them.

My chart max x-axis time is always present time and increases as you pan right.

I've managed to get filtered ticks time as an array `["12:55"]` but the chart still shows all the other time before 12:55 .

[image]

My xAxis configuration

```
 xAxes: [
                {
                    xAxisID: 'x-1',
                    type: "time",
                    time: {
                        unit: "minute",
                        displayFormats: { minute: 'HH:mm' },
                        stepSize: 5,
                        min: chartMin,
                        max: chartDisplayMax,
                    },
                    afterBuildTicks: function (axis) {
                        const { ticks } = axis;
                        const ticksToDisplay= ticks && ticks.filter(tick => tick >= moment().subtract(5, "minutes").format('HH:mm'));
                        return ticksToDisplay;
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        display: true,
                    },
                },
            ],
```

[image]